# What is "Patigha", and how does it differ from "Dosa"?

Tags: theravada, abhidhamma, academic-buddhism

I would like to know what is defined as "Patigha" (Skt. "Pratigha"), and how it varies from "Dosa" (Skt. "Dvesha").

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some sources:

- [Patigha](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/n_r/patigha.htm) (dictionary definition)
- [Lobha,Dosa, Moha versus Raga, Patigha, Avijja](https://puredhamma.net/key-hidden-dhamma-concepts/key-pali-terms-tanha-lobha-dosa-moha/lobhadosa-moha-versus-raga-patigha-avijja/)

Although on an ethical level they're synonymous, pathiga goes deeper than dosa. It's more on the level of (dormant) tendencies.

Answer (score 1):

Dvesha is a base thought of sin, that means dvesha helps to give birth to sins.. Patigha is an advanced form of Dvesha,It's the same which's called as ''**Wyapada**'' ..If your mind has dvesha and it keeps growing towards a certain person on 9 reasons there you grows patigha on your mind..that 9 reasons are..

That person did a bad thing to me

that person will do a bad to me

that person is doing a bad to me

that person did a bad to my friend

.

and so on..wyapada or patigha is a more serious form of dvesha as i said above, so it is called a one of dasa akusala(one of ten sins) also..

Answer (score 0):

Pathiga is the fundamental underlying resistance/aversion that one has towards his own senses which exert pressure on one's mind through either pleasurable or unpleasurable sense objects.
It is the covert resistance/ hate/ self loathing that one has towards one's own senses.
And because it is too painful and one does not want to deal with the truth that you can not owe your senses, that they are, as the Buddha says, empty and hollow , the only thing that is left to do is to blame, hate and be avert to the external unpleasant sense objects.

Comment: There is no such thing as "*fundamental* underlying resistance."